# MassTransit cant connect to Rabbit Broker from Linux but can from Windows - .Net Core 2.1

Tags: linux, ubuntu, .net-core, rabbitmq, masstransit

I have a MassTransit Implementation in a .NET Core 2.1 application.

I developed the application locally on my Windows machine, running off Kestrel.

But when I publish to my hosting server which is Linux Ubuntu. I get the following in the console output:

```
RabbitMQ Connect Failed: Broker unreachable: my_login_name@10.XXX.XXX.XX:5671/
```

**But: I can telnet to broker (TELNET 10.XXX.XXX.XX 5671) from my hosting server**.

Here is how my host is configured:

```
var host = cfg.Host(new Uri("rabbitmq://10.XXX.XXX.XX:5671"), hostConfigurator =>
{
    hostConfigurator.Username("my_login_name");
    hostConfigurator.Password("xxxxx");
    hostConfigurator.UseSsl(ssl =>
    {
        ssl.AllowPolicyErrors(SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateNotAvailable |
                              SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateNameMismatch |
                              SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateChainErrors);
    });
});
```

The Rabbit Broker box is Linux,  CentOS 7.

Everything works fine locally on my **windows** machine, **connecting to the same rabbit broker**.

I really don't know whats going on. Its my first time implementing MassTransit AND hosting on Linux.

But at guess I am wondering would it have something to to do with the SSL portion of the code?

Any ideas?

Comment: We use a massive amount of services with MT and RMQ in production in Kubernetes, with Linux, of course. All works fine. We never used SSL though. I know that Linux won't let .NET app use SSL if the certificate isn't trusted by OS.

Comment: The error message *`RabbitMQ Connect Failed: Broker unreachable`* sounds a bit misleading since you can telnet to the service. My guess is, the Linux service is HTTP, but your RabbitMQ client expects HTTPS. RabbitMQ client receives plain text from Linux Service but RabbitMQ client expects HTTPS protocol data. RabbitMQ client then fails because the TLS handshake does not proceed. I think your next step is to dump the first 16 or 32 bytes received from Linux service. If it is something like `<xml ...`, then you know you are getting HTTP data.

Comment: Also, the `AllowPolicyErrors` looks like a bad choice. Please don't run them in production when using real people's data. It is OK to screw yourself and your company. Just don't screw other unsuspecting people.

Comment: Thanks for the tips Alexey and jww. I will look at removing the requirement for SSL on the Rabbit Client maybe. jww - this is an internal test server and there is no ones data being sent, just some calculated data.